# CSS Glitch with text and COL bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i have been coding on a template and there seams to be a problem when articles from my website are being echoed,
 Here is my code (Note: This code is the same twice just with a different content)

`<section class="slice bg-5">
        <div class="w-section inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                                                                           <div class="col-md-5" style="display:inline-block;">            <h3>IceSword</h3>
            <p> Voici un news </p>
    </div>`

HERE IS A IMAGE -------------------------> https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5suv.jpg

Comment: As it stands at the moment, it looks like you are missing some closing tags, but there is not enough code to be sure.

Comment: No i have all my closing tags i just forgot to insert them

Comment: I'm afraid this question is rather a mess. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry could you help me please? it is pretty anoying

Answer (score 0):

in real world scenario the words not as long as you are using in demo.

i mean if the word is too much long (without space) then it will break through its container, you can apply word-break rule but its not necessary.

just try demo with some real paragraph or lorem ipsum paragraph, not with a series of single characters without space.

but if you explicitly want to break words then try this css property:

`p {word-break:break-all;}`